# Tkinter cell location (x,y)?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to get the cell size and x,y location of a cell's corner?I have radio buttons on the left side of my frame and I would like to resize an image based on the size of the frame.

What I'm going to end up doing is creating a block that takes up a large group of cells that will allow me to zoom in on my .tif and scroll left/right and up/down. Does this type of widget already exist?

Here's a *very* rough outline of what I currently have

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os

file_path = "C:/Users/..."
dirs = os.listdir(file_path)


root = Tk()
# Set window size slightly below screen size
width = int(root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_screenwidth()/9)
height = int(root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_screenheight()/9)
root.geometry(str(width)+"x"+str(height))



class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        os.chdir(file_path)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,
            text = "Available Files"
            ).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        Label(self,
            text = "Select one:"
            ).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.filelist = StringVar()
        self.filelist.set(0)
        # Radio buttons of files in directory
        i = 1
        for files in dirs:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(file_path, files)):
                i += 1
                Radiobutton(self,
                            text=files,
                            variable=self.filelist,
                            value=files,
                            command=self.update_text
                            ).grid(row=i,column=0,sticky=W)
        # Message box
        self.result = Text(self, width=40, height=5, wrap=WORD)
        self.result.grid(row=i, column=0, columnspan=3)

    def update_text(self):
        message = "File selected is "
        message += self.filelist.get()
        self.display_image()
        self.result.delete(0.0, END)
        self.result.insert(0.0, message)

    def display_image(self):
        try:
            self.image = Image.open(self.filelist.get())
        except:
            message += self.filelist.get() + " doesn't exist. This is awkward..."

        img_width,img_height = self.image.size
        self.preview_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.preview = Label(self, image=self.preview_image)
        self.preview.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=20)

    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "cell"? A "cell" in a `grid` layout? Or just any widget? In the latter case, check out the `winfo` ,methods, e.g. `winfo_x()`

Comment: Could you please provide some code to demostrate your problem?

Comment: With cell I do mean using the grid layout.

Comment: There is at least one indentation problem in your code - it looks like you're creating an instance of `Application` inside the `display_image` method.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the indentation. That was a pasting error.